# _vm.$refs.menu.open is not a function

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue-context to modify the default context menu, which I call from a component but when I try to interact with it I get an error, here's my code

```
<!-- Main -->
<p @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.menu.open">test</p>
<Context reference="menu" />

<script>
    import Context from './map/context.vue'
    export default { components: { Context } }
</script>

<!-- Component -->
<vue-context :ref="reference" :close-on-click="true" :close-on-scroll="true">
    <li>
        <a>
            Do something
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
            Do something else
        </a>
    </li>
</vue-context>
<script>
    import VueContext from 'vue-context'
    import 'vue-context/dist/css/vue-context.css'
    export default {
        props: ['reference'],
        components: {
            VueContext
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I right click on the page, I get the error `_vm.$refs.menu.open is not a function`

Comment: if you don't bind that prop like `<vue-context ref="menu"` does it work?

Comment: I get the error `_vm.$refs.menu is undefined`

Comment: could you provide an example in codesandbox in order to debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you wrapped VueContext inside a separate vue instance, the outer Vue instance (the one containing the `@contextmenu` call) does not have a `$refs.menu`. You can access the child's `$refs` by setting a ref on the child itself:

```
<p @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.wrapper.$refs.menu.open">test</p>
<Context ref="wrapper" reference="menu" />
```

See it [working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-heyrovsky-vcec6?file=/src/App.vue).

---

I'd also argue you shouldn't pass the string `'menu'` from parent but specify it directly inside `<Context>`'s template.
Dynamic props only make sense when you have some benefit from them changing value, which is clearly not the case here. You need that child `ref` to always be `'menu'` so you can access its methods:

```
<p @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.wrapper.$refs.menu.open">test</p>
<Context ref="wrapper" />
```

Context.vue:

```
<template>
  <vue-context ref="menu" :close-on-click="true" :close-on-scroll="true">
    <li><a>Do something</a></li>
    <li><a>Do something else</a></li>
  </vue-context>
</template>
<script>
  import VueContext from "vue-context";
  import "vue-context/dist/css/vue-context.css";
  export default { components: { VueContext } };
</script>
```

---

To summarize: `$refs` is a unified mechanism allowing you to access template elements, whether they're DOM elements or Vue instances.

Each component only contains its own `$refs`. To access the `$refs` of one of its children, you have to give the child a `ref` in parent scope and use `$refs` on that particular reference.
This actually makes a lot of sense in a scenario where you want multiple context menus with different contents for different items in your parent component (although you're probably better off simply passing down the menu items and their actions dynamically to a single context menu instance).